# When should we v-model or refs in the effective way?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

In Vue, we can use `v-model` or `ref()` in [Template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to **manipulate the data**. In most cases we can use them interchangeably.

So I really don't see any major benefits when Vue provides refs.

Can anyone give me some experiences to use them in the effective way?

Comment: I think you mean `reactive` not `v-model`

Comment: What do you mean `refs`? [Template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html)? Or [`ref()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) reactive wrapper? In both cases, they have nothing to deal with `v-model`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for unclear question. I was intended to template ref

Comment: "In most cases" - which cases? If you have specific ones in mind, please, provide code for them. The question isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about [`Template Refs`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html), them  I would suggest you to read the Vue Docs carefully, to understand what [`Template Refs`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) were designed for.

The Documentation shows also the practical examples of using `Template Refs`.

In case, when someone questions, what is the `ref()` function was wade for, here is the best article from [Bartosz Salwiczek](https://medium.com/@bsalwiczek), I have read about this topic.

Medium: [Ref() vs Reactive() in Vue 3 — what’s the right choice?](https://medium.com/@bsalwiczek/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3-whats-the-right-choice-7c6f7265ce39)

Comment: Please list the summary of information that you grabbed from these external links. Because any external link might be broken anytime and it is better for the person who wants to scan the answer quickly